# Access control in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, access-control

I am implementing a medium sized Qt app in which I would like to implement access control for some actions. The application tracks currently logged in user and has an authorization function with two overloads

`bool authorize(action)`

and

`bool authorize(action, username, password)`.

The first one checks if the currently logged in user has permissions for the action, and the second tries to authorize the user given with the arguments.

I would like to check if the user has permissions for the action (usually triggered with a button). If the user has permissions, the action executes normally, otherwise an authorization widget pops up. A user with permissions  can than either authorize the action (one action only) or cancel it.

Is there a way of achieving this, without dynamically connecting each action to an intermediate widget that checks for permissions?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder from your security-aware friends: Security by asking a user to authenticate is worth nothing when used without crypto, because anyone that can handle a debugger will be able to break your application's "security".

Comment: Your app probably shouldn't be handling the authorisation directly? What platforms are you targeting? For example, in OS X, an application would hand off authorisation to the system, which is responsible for requesting the user's credentials and will tell your application whether or not access should be granted.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with reimplementing [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) for the class where you need to verify the action.